# inotify does not work with linux kernel 3.4.11

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, inotify

I have a Linux running with kernel 3.4.11.

I tried to run `inotify-tools`, but it does not work (in fact it does not detect the file changes).

I checked the `.config` file of Linux kernel and I found the following lines:

```
CONFIG_FSNOTIFY=y
# CONFIG_DNOTIFY is not set
CONFIG_INOTIFY_USER=y
```

Should I set the:

```
CONFIG_DNOTIFY=y
```

In order to get the `inotifyd` working?

Comment: Do a `strace` on the binary that you are running. Is it doing a `fcntl` to monitor a directory ?

Comment: No, `CONFIG_DNOTIFY` should not need to be set. Dnotify and Inotify are separate things (Inotify replaced Dnotify if I understand it correctly).